# Stop the 'submit' button value from being passed via GET?

Tags: html, forms, get, submit

I'm trying to pass form information via GET - this is important so that people can send the filtered data from their form selections to other people.

The problem is, using the code below, it not only passes the filter information, but also the submit form value like so: index.php?month_filter=Feb&year_filter=12&**Submit=Filter+Table**

```
<form name="filter_form" action="<?php echo CURRENT_PAGE ?>" method="get">
<input name="Submit" type="submit" class="button" value="Filter Table">
```

Long shot, but is there a way to remove the submit button from the URL? Thanks!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you remove the `name` attribute, it will not get passed through in GET/POST.